# Finding the cluster that an instance got assigned to with Weka

Tags: java, weka

Im using an EM clusterer with an AddCluster Filter in order to see what instances are getting assigned to the different clusters after training. Below is the code that I'm using.  I'm faily sure that I am applying the filter correctly but once I have the new Instances I still dont know how to get the cluster info from them.  Im sure its just a simple getBlah() call but I'm just not locating it.  Thanks in advance.

```
public Cluster()
{
    clusterer = new EM();
    filter = new AddCluster();

    try
    {
        clusterer.setMaxIterations(100);
        clusterer.setNumClusters(20);
        filter.setClusterer(clusterer);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void buildCluster(String fileName)
{
    try
    {
        DataSource source = new DataSource(fileName);
        inst = source.getDataSet();
        filter.setInputFormat(inst);
        inst = AddCluster.useFilter(inst, filter);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use "Dictionary" Class. Here is my example code:

```
Enumeration clusteredInst = data_to_use.enumerateInstances();<br> 
Dictionary<Integer, ArrayList<Instance>> clusteredSamples = new ashtable<>();


while (clusteredInst.hasMoreElements()) {<br> 
            Instance ins = (Instance) clusteredInst.nextElement();<br> 
            int clusterNumb = em.clusterInstance(ins);<br> 
            ArrayList<Instance> cls = null;<br> 
            cls = clusteredSamples.get(clusterNumb);<br> 
            if (cls != null) {<br> 
                cls.add(ins);<br> 
            } else {<br> 
                cls = new ArrayList<>();<br> 
                cls.add(ins);<br> 
                //you add elements to dictionary using put method<br> 
                //put(key, value)<br> 
                clusteredSamples.put(clusterNumb, cls);<br> 
            }
        }
```

And you also can retrieval your data from dictionary by call it's Key.